# How to use A4 paper with seminar package and PostScript?

Tags: latex

I have a lot of old sizes made with the seminar package and pstricks.

Is it possible to rotate the slide, so it will bit on a A4 paper and still using PostScript?

```
\documentclass[a4]{seminar}
\usepackage{pstcol,pstricks,pst-text}
\usepackage{fancybox,times,slidesec}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{semcolor,epsfig,changebar,rotating,multicol}

\newsavebox\headbox
\renewcommand{\makeslideheading}[1]{%
 \gdef\theslideheading{#1}%
 \begin{lrbox}{\headbox}\large\bfseries#1\end{lrbox}%
 \begin{center}\ovalbox{\usebox\headbox}\end{center}}

\newpagestyle{cern}
   {{\color{red}\small \textbf{+}\hfil \today \hfil \textbf{+}}}
   {{\color{black}\small \textbf{+}\hfil \thepage \hfil \textbf{+}}}
\pagestyle{cern}

\date{\vspace{-0.20 cm}2009}
\title{\bf A}

\author{
  me
}

\begin{document}

\slideframe{shadow}
%\slideplacement{here}
\setlength\paperwidth{210mm}
\setlength\paperheight{297mm}
\input{sem-page.sty}
\setlength\slidewidth{208mm}
\setlength\slideheight{160mm}
\renewcommand\slideleftmargin{1.0in}
\renewcommand\sliderightmargin{1.0in}

\begin{slide}
\maketitle
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with

```
latex symmetrics.tex
dvips -t landscape symmetrics.dvi
evince symmetrics.ps
```

Answer (score 2):

you seem to already have found a decent answer. Another method would be to convert to pdf (`ps2pdf`) then use the powerful PDF toolkit ([`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)) which is available in the Ubuntu repositories.